# Возможно ли сделать сортировку в JPQL по свойству enum?

Tags: java, spring, enum, spring-data-jpa, jpql

**Сущность**:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "shapes")
public class Shape {

    @Id
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    ShapeType type;
}
```

**Enum**:

```java
public enum ShapeType {

    RECTANGLE("Прямоугольник"),
    SQUARE("Квадрат"),
    CIRCLE("Круг");

    private final String name;

    ShapeType(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Я хочу сделать сортировку по свойству `name` поля `type` при получении списка фигур. В моём понимании это было бы как-то так:

```java
@Query("SELECT s FROM Shape s ORDER BY s.type.name ASC")
List<Shape> getAll();
```

Но такой запрос генерирует ошибку:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: com.zhenyria.project.model.Shape
```

Существует ли какая-то возможность сортировки по полю самого `enum`? Может быть поможет переопределение метода `compareTo()` или что-то в этом роде?

**Важно: сортировка должна происходить на уровне БД. Я использую пагинацию, поэтому вариант с сортировкой в коде не подходит!**

Comment: А что `ORDER BY s.type` не работает? Поле `type` сущности `Shape` на уровне базы представлено как раз значением из поля `name`. Должно работать.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я забивал тестовые данные вручную прямо вот так: SQUARE и работало нормально. И насколько помню, оно представляется именно как название самого объекта enum, а не его значений.

Comment: @RomanKonoval ну и я посмотрел поле name - это немного другое, там поле приватное, и соответственно к моему полю оно отношения не имеет. Ну и к тому же метод получения этого поля - name(), этот метод final, т.е. не переопределяется

Comment: Точно, это я перепутал `name` enum-а и ваше поле, изначально понял так, что вы хотите по полю enum-а. Сейчас в БД нигде не фигурирует ваше поле и его значение, так что на уровне базы при таком мапинге никак такую сортировку не организовать - попросту данные в БД не хранятся. Нужно менять мапинг, чтоб именно ваше поле сохранялось в БД.

Comment: @RomanKonoval похоже, что так... Решил проблему немного по-другому. Теперь в бд сохраняется значение моё значение name, а не сам енум.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сортировка работала, я реализовал конвертацию `enum` при сохранении в базу данных.

Начиная с `JPA 2.1` имеется аннотация `@Converter`. Конвертер преобразует атрибут при сохранении и возвращает к изначальному типу при получении.

Код моего конвертера:

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ShapeTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ShapeType, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ShapeType attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public ShapeType convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData == null
                ? null
                : Stream.of(ShapeType.values())
                .filter(t -> t.getName().equals(dbData))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(
                        String.format("ShapeType with name %s is not exist", dbData)));
    }
}
```

Теперь можно убрать аннотацию `@Enumerated` над полем `ShapeType` в сущности `Shape`. Если бы я не указал в аннотации `autoApply=true`, то пришлось бы отмечать поле аннотацией `@Converter`. А так Spring автоматически будет преобразовывать этот тип при любом сохранении в базу данных.

Теперь можно указывать сортировку по полю `type` и она будет корректно работать:

```java
@Query("SELECT s FROM Shape s ORDER BY s.type ASC")
List<Shape> getAll();
```

Отсортированный вывод объектов `Shape` будет не такой *(классическая сортировка по полю имени enum, которое сохраняется в базу данных при использовании `@Enumarated(EnumType.STRING)`)*:

```js
{id: 1001, type: CIRCLE("Круг")},
{id: 2321, type: RECTANGLE("Прямоугольник")},
{id: 1102, type: SQUARE("Квадрат")}
```

а такой *(здесь мы уже сохраняем не имя enum, а значение, в которое мы его конвертируем при сохранении в базу данных)*:

```js
{id: 1102, type: SQUARE("Квадрат")},
{id: 1001, type: CIRCLE("Круг")},
{id: 2321, type: RECTANGLE("Прямоугольник")}
```